# What should I do to get my answer upvoted?

Tags: support

This https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/94162/4188 has an upvote, while mine https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/94161/4188 doesn't. Mine is older by a few minutes, has sources and photos. What else should I do to get my answer upvoted?

Comment: Everything all right, your answer is on the top now.

Answer (score 5):

Photos and sources don't always make it better ;)  It's one of those things, if they're the same # of votes, it'll present answers in a random order, but once one is 'winning' it appears at the top, unless another is accepted, in which case that one appears at the top.

You could try sharing directly to your answer on twitter or reddit etc, but it's up to voters to choose which they vote for.

EDIT: Yours also has more votes than the other now anyway ;)